# Xamarin Android Make background Transparent

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I'm trying to Display a png Picture on an Operation which is successfully Completed, I wish to make the Background Transparent

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/successful"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**In Activity**

```
Dialog alert;
alert = new Dialog(this);
alert.SetContentView(Resource.Layout.SuccessfulPopup);
alert.Show();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure your image's background is transparent** i.e. when you open it in an image viewer it should have a transparent background.

If you want a transparent background just use the hex code of White/Black and add 80 before it:

So if you are doing this in In XML it would be something like:

```
android:background="#80000000"
```

And if you are doing it through the code it would be something like:

```
imageView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Parse("#80000000"));
```

or

```
imageView.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
```

### Update:

This is how your XAML should look

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/successful"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
```

Comment: Yes , it was Transparent , android:background="#80000000"  worked, Thanks a Ton !

Comment: Sure, if this worked for you kindly mark it correct & upvote

Comment: I tried android:background="#80000000"   , see this link it Looking something like this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UDxeWDuJHPqAey6LJE5sNOGULS1oKXpz/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I would love to accept the answer , but did you saw that picture , Need your help with that Too  , I hope i am not being mean , Just new to Xamarin , So struck with it

Comment: Not mean at all do not worry about it

Comment: I think There would be some other factor this is not helping in my case , I Even changed Xaml , I am using this xaml as a dialog , Do you think there is Something to Fix Not in This Layout ?

Comment: Can you upload the image you have used and link it here?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WHwf_ZjOjRzN9YVAYu2bltrsdpdwIUfo/view?usp=sharing here

Comment: Not a screenshot the actual image that you are using the correct mark inside the circle that image!!!

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Bz5t6LJoXDylIt247vjPccvvFCOJyEnx/view?usp=sharing Here

Comment: True  , Sides Still Showing , I wanna remove them only , not center